# WordPress - enable/disable a div like a widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I am building a custom WordPress site with my own theme.  Is there a way in WordPress that would allow me to enable or disable a div in the sidebar similar to the way I enable or disable a widget?

For example, I have a div that is for a newsletter subscription form and a div that is for a call-to-action button.  Is there a way that I can allow the WordPress administrator to choose which page to have the newsletter subscription form and which page to have the call-to-action button dynamically?

I have been searching but was unable to find any information.  Perhaps I didn't have the right keyword?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For that to happen you would either have to go for the somewhat tricky solution, but on the other hand more satisfactory; create a custom options page with a true/false-solution using the Settings API. You can read more about that over at Codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API . They here refer to a handfull of external resources to learn more. This guide helped me when setting up my first built-from-scratch page; http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/ .

The other solution would be to use a plugin. The top shelf, best in class solution - if you ask me - would be Advanced Custom Fields; http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ . It's a little bit of work to first get it's head around, perhaps, but when you get going you'll probably never look back. Creating awesome options pages is a breeze, and you probably will end up making all sorts of elements on your page optional - just because you can. But there's a catch; to create options pages you will have to buy the Pro version of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @danjah!  I think the ACF route would be the right way to go.  I have used ACF for some custom fields before but never tried it for the scenario I described above.  I was just thinking of how I can potentially use ACF for this type of application and I think I have some better ideas now!  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need a more specific ACF-solution.